# Printing on same line and add count in one line one time in c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

how to show output ( Number of grades above the Average + Grades above or equal the Average ) in same line i don't wont new line for each number + how to print these one time not many times , i mean because i use for loop it print `Number of grades above the Average` every number in one line  i want just the count in one line how to do this

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

    
int main()
{
    int G,N;
    float num[100], sum=0.0, average;
    
    
    cout << "Enter the numbers of Student : ";
    cin >> N;

    while (N > 500 || N <= 1)
    {
        cout << "Error ! number of student should in range of (1 to 500)." << endl;
        cout << "Enter the number again: ";
        cin >> N;
    }

    for(G = 0; G < N; ++G)
    {
        cout << G + 1 << ". Enter " << G + 1 << " Mark : ";
        cin >> num[G];
        sum += num[G];
    }

    // find average
    average = sum / N;
    cout <<endl<< "Grades Average = " << average <<endl<<endl;
  
     // find Grades above or equal the Average  
    cout<<"Grades above or equal the Average : "<< endl;
    for (G = 0; G < N; ++G){
        if (num[G] >= average){
            cout << num[G] << endl;
        }
    }
  
    // find Number of grades above the Average  
    cout<<endl;
    for (G = 0; G < N; ++G){
        if (num[G] >= average){
            cout << "Number of grades above the Average : " << G + 1 << endl;
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just get rid of the `endl`.

Comment: a general tip: don't use code that you don't understand what it does. This time it is `endl` next time it might be worse

Comment: You may be able to get away with using `\r`, which is a carriage return (to the beginning of the line), but the actual behavior may differ by console.  Some consoles may translate `'\r'` to a newline.

Comment: Here you declare the array to have up to 100 elements: `float num[100]` then allow N to be 500. You will have undefined behavior if N is greater than 100.

Comment: and that is a good example of why using raw "magic numbers"  such as 100 or 500, instead of named constants, is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues with your code:

- `num[]` can hold 100 values max, but you are allowing the user to enter up to 500 values into it, thus you have the potential for a buffer overflow.
- you say the valid number of students is `1 to 500`, but you are preventing the user from entering `1`.
- lack of adequate error handling when reading the user's input.
- you are outputting `"Number of grades above the Average : "` inside the loop for every matching grade, which you say you don't want. You should instead output it *once* before entering the loop, then use the loop to *count* the matching grades without outputting each one, then output the final count *after* the loop is finished.

Try this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

const int maxStudents = 500;

int main()
{
    int G, N, nAverages = 0;
    float num[maxStudents], sum = 0.0, average;
    
    cout << "Enter the number of Students : ";
    do
    {
        if (cin >> N)
        {
            if (N >= 1 && N <= maxStudents)
                break;

            cout << "Error ! Number of students should be in range of (1 to " << maxStudents << ")." << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Error ! Invalid input." << endl;
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }

        cout << "Enter the number again: ";
    }
    while (true);

    for(G = 0; G < N; ++G)
    {
        cout << G + 1 << ". Enter Mark : ";
        while (!(cin >> num[G]))
        {
            cout << "Error ! Invalid input." << endl;
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            cout << "Enter the mark again: ";
        }
        sum += num[G];
    }

    // find average
    average = sum / N;
    cout << endl << "Grades Average = " << average << endl << endl;
  
    // find Grades above or equal the Average  
    cout << "Grades above or equal the Average : " << endl;
    for (G = 0; G < N; ++G){
        if (num[G] >= average){
            cout << G + 1 << ": " << num[G] << endl;
            ++nAverages;
        }
    }
  
    // Number of grades above the Average  
    cout << endl << "Number of grades above the Average : " << nAverages << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: yes yes thank you bro i'm now understood the problem thank you